# 380V Wye on motor nameplace,VFD manual requires 220V delta. Will it work?

Tags: motor, vfd

I removed a motor (nameplate attached) from an eddy current drive. My intention was to replace the controller with a VFD and remove the clutch assembly. The motor obviously ran at full speed with each coil connected to 220V 3 phase in star config.
[image]

As you can see on the nameplate the motor is rated at 380V star. There is a terminal box with 6 terminals for star/delta configuration but does the nameplace suggest the motor only runs on star config?

I want to use this [VFD](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwi2k57c6pXtAhUT7e0KHZwEAv4YABAEGgJkZw&ae=2&sig=AOD64_0si3Du287EjVEQWfr03I3OeMiLFA&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjS6Zfc6pXtAhVUtHEKHdQWBQEQwg96BAgjEBM&dct=1&adurl=) but the motor needs to be rated for 220V delta and my motor is rated at 380V star.

Thanks in advanced for any assistance.

Comment: You have linked to a Bangbang advert instead of a datasheet or user manual. There are reasons why they're cheap and not providing documentation is one of them.

Comment: if you open up the wiring box and there's only two jumper bars (or a sigle bar with three holes) that may be why delta is not offered on the nameplate. I see no reason why this motor would not work wired as delta.

Comment: do you need the motor to run at full speed?

Comment: @Transistor I have the manual. The manual basically states the same as the ad - 220V output on the each of the 3 phases.

Comment: @Jasen Yes, there is only 2 jumper bars. No, I will not be running at full speed. Motor will be connected to a core machine which requires more torque than speed.

Comment: The nameplate specifically says "Y connection", beside the IP44 rating.

Comment: Since your other question indicates that the neutral connection is not in the conduit box, the answer by @Jason may be the best alternative. You can set the VFD to operate the motor with the wye connection as a 220 V, 29 Hz, 1.7 kW motor. The maximum speed will be about 786 RPM. The motor will be capable of close to the same torque as it produces at 3kW, 1420 RPM. It would tend to get a little hotter than at full speed, so continuous operation at rated ambient temperature may not be advisable.

Answer (score 1):

If you can properly reconnect the motor in delta, there should be no reason that it will not run properly on 230 volts. There may be a transformer winding in the motor used to power the eddy-current controller. Be sure to insulate any unused wires coming out of the motor.

Answer (score 1):

A star connected motor can be used on a delta supply.

Below 58% speed the VFD will only need 220VAC output or lower, so you may be able to use the motor unmodified.

Else you'll need to find, or fabricate, another jumper bar so that you can rewire the motor as delta

This arrangement would be three jumpers parallel in the vertical direction instead of horizontal with the feed connected to the jumpers too

```
   _     _     _
  |O|   |O|   |o|
  | |   | |   | |
  | |   | |   | |
  |O|   |o|   |o|
 / ~   / ~   / ~
U     V     W
```

Comment: Is ASCII art making a comeback?